# Changing the way we pin "accepted" answers to the top? (Update)

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

### Decision

On December 17th, the vote total was 3-2 in favor of unpinning. However, neither option reached the minimum number of votes (5) or minimum amount more than the other option (3). Therefore, the current pinning status will remain and the meta table will be marked "50/50".

### Update (Tyberius)

Since my answer at the time was somewhat vague and predicated on the new default sort being by vote (they eventually settled on leaving the default of keeping the accepted answer pinned), I wanted to reopen this discussion to gauge users' opinions and actually have a clear vote for one option or the other. I have added answers below that show support for keeping the accepted pinned or removing the pin; simply upvote your preferred option (to avoid double counting, don't downvote the other option). Note pinning/unpinning doesn't remove the green checkmark, it only changes where the answer appears in the sorted list.

If you wanted to say why you voted for a particular option, you can comment below that option, not the opposing one. I deleted my original answer to leave a clean slate and not have additional posts arguing for one side or the other. I would rather not have debates in the comments, but if you wanted to discuss someone's reasoning, that would be fine in the [main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107323).

Here is my proposed acceptance criteria (open to suggestions):

- We will make a decision based on the vote totals on **December 17th**. The date is a bit arbitrary, but it gives more than two full weeks to come to a decision and ends the voting period before the stretch of holidays at the end of December.
- The decision will be the answer with the most upvotes assuming it has at least **5** upvotes (to ensure there was enough voting) and at least **3** more upvotes than the other answer (avoids a narrow split decision). This decision will be marked in the [table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369914/374097) on main Meta and (if changes are needed) the CMs will be contacted to make the change.
- If neither post meets these criteria, we will continue with the default of leaving the accepted answer pinned. The meta table will be marked with "50/50" to say that a consensus was not reached.

### Original Post

SE [is making the way accepted answers behave configurable per-site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/263383) and is looking for input from our side as to what our preference is.

Currently, accepted answers - answers that the asker of the question has explicitly marked as answering their question - always are shown at the top of the list of answers when sorting by votes, regardless of whether there is an answer with a higher score. In the future, it seems we will be able to decide that instead it should just be sorted by its votes, ignoring its status as the accepted answer.

So, what are your opinions on this topic? Would you like the answer to be unpinned, and if so, why? Would you like the behaviour to stay as it is? Again - if so, why?

Note that in the linked meta question there is a deadline by Sept 19th for SE to decide what the *default* on all sites will be going forward, but this post is about your preference for the behaviour of accepted answers *on mattermodeling.SE*, not about your preference for the default for all sites.

---

<sup>*Copied from the [equivalent question on physics.SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13811/58382)*</sup>

Answer (score 4):

### Leave Accepted Answer Pinned

Upvote this answer if you would like the accepted answer to be first, followed by the answers sorted by vote total.

Answer (score 2):

### Unpin Accepted Answer

Upvote this answer if you would like to see the accepted answer unpinned and answers sorted strictly by vote total.